# Animating SVG with snap after loading into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I just started working with snap.svg and am a little lost.

What i am trying to achieve is the following. From my JavaScript file I want to load a SVG into a div. Then, once hovered upon A element inside the SVG will animate. I have been able to get this code working on page, but I would like to keep all the JavaScript code in a JavaScript file.

Here is the on page code that currently works:

```
 window.onload = function () {
     var s = Snap(100, 100);
     Snap.load("/flatui/images/icons/responsive.svg", function (f) {

         redSomething = f.select("#phone");

         redSomething.hover(function () {
             redSomething.animate({ transform: 't100,0' }, 2000);
         });

         s.append(f);
     });

 };
```

Here is the code i am trying to run in my JS file:

```
var s = Snap(".responsive-ani");
var l = Snap.load("/flatui/images/icons/responsive.svg", onSVGLoaded ) ;

function onSVGLoaded( data ){ 
 redSomething = l.select("#phone");
 redSomething.hover(function () {
     redSomething.animate({ transform: 't100,0' }, 2000);
 });
s.append( data );
}
```

Comment: I think you may need to change Snap(".responsive-ani"); to select the Id of a div you want to use, rather than a class, or let Snap create the svg element, like Snap(400,400); If you can pop the example on a jsfiddle or jsbin, it should be a bit easier to check.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote it differently and now it seems to work, Using jquery for the hover.

```
window.onload = function () {
var s = Snap(".responsive-icon");
var l = Snap.load("http://new.beresponsive.co.za/wp-content/themes/responsive/flatui/images/icons/responsive.svg", function(f) {
 phone = f.select("#phone");
 tablet = f.select("#tablet");
 jQuery('.responsive-icon').hover(function () {
     phone.animate({ transform: 't-52,12' }, 300);
     tablet.animate({ transform: 't20,-15' }, 300);
 },function(){
     phone.animate({ transform: 't0,0' }, 600);
     tablet.animate({ transform: 't0,0' }, 600);
});
s.append( f );
});
}
```